# Pycharm DeepBugs | Possibly wrong order of function arguments (in correct code)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, jetbrains-deepbugs

**This is the package that is giving me the errors.**

[image]

---

Here I have a simple piece of code that prints length.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
print("Hello", len(a))
# Output: Hello 3
```

This works fine when I execute it. But for some reason Pycharm DeepBugs seems to be mad at it

"Fix order of arguments" from tooltip gives me `print(len(a), len(a))`

[image]

- Is the code having any problem that I am missing?
- or is JetBrains plugin broken?

Comment: What does "Fix order of arguments" give you?

Comment: Your code is valid. The 1st param to [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) is `*objects`.

Comment: "Fix order of arguments" is even more broken it gives me "print(len(a), len(a))"

Comment: Perhaps it is because you are printing strings and integers as separate arguments on the same print method. Whenever I want to print integers and strings together I always use something like print(“string” + str(len(a)))

Comment: @Pokebab, DeepBugs does not complain for code `print("Hello", str(len(a)))` so you could be right. BUT even without str() the code runs just fine and pycharm does not flag any PEP8 violation.

Comment: DeepBugs is flagging this piece of code too `"hello_world!".upper().replace("_", " ")` which again runs perfectly fine

Comment: @Srinath Ganesh - notice that it’s not actually an Error, it’s more of a suggestion from Pycharm, that’s why it says “possibly”, it does it when you don’t adhere to it’s standard of writing python. For example, many times I have come across a similar pop up when Pycharm suspects that I’m going to get a reference before declaration error, even though I know it won’t, and that PyCharm has not realised I’ve paid careful attention to where and when a function is referenced in order before the actual written code, but not called until after.

Comment: Yes that could be a possibility. but it comes with Red Underline (as apposed to Yello Underline for warnings). OR maybe DeepBugs plugin is not stable yet

Comment: The red underline is annoying at times, however it otherwise does a good job at spotting things that could upset the functionality of your program that the python shell would not raise an error code for. You should treat it more as advice that you can choose to ignore, rather than a real error.